# sql server query to assign 2 different column values for each half of rows

Tags: sql-server, divide

I have the following table with three columns:

tb1

```
userID   itemID   rating
```

This table contains information about the ratings given by users to different items.
A user can give ratings to multiple items, and an item can receive ratings from multiple users.

I need to **update the rating** values for this table, so that **half the items** in tb1 should be assigned 5 rating and other half should be assigned 1 rating.

Note: This means that while a user can give different ratings to different items, an item can have either all its ratings as 1 or all ratings as 5.

Initially, the rating values are NULL for all pairs of users and items.

This task could be performed using two separate queries.

```
 UPDATE tb1
    SET rating = 5 
  WHERE itemID IN 
        (SELECT top(50) percent itemID
           FROM tb1 
          GROUP BY itemID
          ORDER BY newid());

 UPDATE tb1
    SET rating = 1
  WHERE rating IS NULL
```

Is there a way to combine both these queries into a single query?

Comment: your `itemID` datatype is??

Comment: itemid -> smallint
  and rating -> float

Comment: You need to elaborate more, what I understand with this is: on click of an item 50% rows of that item will mark as 1 and other 50% as 5 for a specific user id.

Comment: A user can rate an item only once. 
What I want is an update query which modifies the rating of 50% items (not rows of an item) as 1 and the other 50% as 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't state if it matters if the first half are 1 and the second half are 5s only that 50% should be each.

If it doesn't matter then you can do something like this:

```
 UPDATE tb1
    SET rating =
        (CASE
             WHEN itemId <=
                  (SELECT MAX(itemID)
                     FROM 
                          (SELECT TOP (50) percent itemID
                             FROM tb1 
                            GROUP BY itemID
                            ORDER BY itemID
                          ) x
                  ) THEN 5
             ELSE 1
         END)
```

Or if your records don't have any deleted items or you're not strictly concerned about being exactly 50% then you could simply do something like this:

```
 UPDATE tb1
    SET rating = CASE
                     WHEN (itemID % 2) = 1 THEN 1
                     ELSE 5
                  END
```

the benefit of this approach is you can do things like this:

```
UPDATE tb1
   SET rating = 
       CASE (itemID % 5) 
            WHEN 1 THEN 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 7
            WHEN 3 THEN 10
            WHEN 4 THEN 40
            ELSE 5
        END
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer Seph. Yes, it doesn't matter whether 1st half is one or second. Ideally, I would have liked the items to have been picked randomly, but if that's not possible to do with a single query then your first query would do the job for me. 

There are missing IDs in the items list, so the second approach, although useful, would not be that beneficial in this particular case.